# Корректно ли сравнение double с нулём?

Tags: c

Именно с нулём, а не другим double-числом.
Гарантирован ли правильный результат при нижеследующем сравнении?

```
double i = 0;
    if (i == 0) {
}
```

Comment: В данном случае, **безусловно гарантирован**.

Вы путаете просто сравнение значения переменной с 0 с сравнением результатов вычисления какой-либо формулы, которые *математически* д.б. равны нулю с сравнением *реальных результатов этих вычислений* с нулем.

Думаю, идея понятна.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо.
Просто и splint, и gcc -Wfloat-equal сыплют предупреждения даже в таком очевидном случае, что меня и смутило.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, работа с `double` в C производится в соответствии с рекомендацией IEEE 754, по которой нулем считаются числа, находящиеся в интервале между минимально возможным по модулю отрицательным и положительным числом, поэтому сравнение `double` с нулем с точки зрения синтаксиса будет корректна.

```
if(i==0.0){//также вполне корректно
}
if(i!=0.0000001){
}
```

Другой вопрос, корректно ли это будет с точки зрения алгоритма, в некоторых случаях требуется проверить на "примерное равенство", тогда следует использовать точность (до тысячной и пр.).

```
double eps=0.001;
if(fabs(i)<eps){//считаем, что он равен нулю
//...
}
```

Надеюсь, был полезен.

Comment: Большое спасибо, не знал.

Comment: не успел прочитать дополнение, что gcc дает предупреждение на это, но, насколько я помню, приведение будет именно таким, от int к double и сравниваться будут, как это интуитивно ожидается, два double.

Comment: Вообще-то приведение будет проведено прямо во время компиляции (поскольку фигурируют одни константы) и в результирующем коде будут только FLT операции.

Comment: Да, спасибо за поправку, это убедительно.